# Singleton, startup and log4j initialization: No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: java, log4j, singleton, wildfly, startup

We wrote a simple class like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
[...]
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ContactFormScheduler {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ContactFormScheduler.class);
```

[...]

When we start server (WildFly 10.1.0) we got the following error:

**15:35:27,142 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.test.ContactFormScheduler).**

**15:35:27,143 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.**

Any hints? What's the best way to initialize log4j?

In web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Others classes logs correctly.

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: What are you using to configure log4j?

Comment: I edited my question with configuration

Comment: `@Startup` EJB gets called during application initialization. I am assuming that Wildfly didn't initialize Log4J during application initialization (deployment) stage so that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: Ok. So I should try to put LOG4J initialization BEFORE EJB's. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude log4j from being in your `WAR/lib` directory, remove the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and move the `log4j.properties` to `WAR/WEB-INF/classes` WildFly automatically configure log4j for your deployment.

If you'd rather use your own version of log4j you'd still need to move your `log4j.properties` to `WAR/WEB-INF/classes` directory as log4j wouldn't be able to read anything from the `WAR/WEB-INF` directory.

Comment: Others log call works fine. I think the problem is related to the order in which log4j and singleton are loaded. If i put 
    log = Logger.getLogger(ContactFormScheduler.class); 
"after" in the execution it works